# Multiple forms in a single list

Tags: list-form

I have a list which has around 100-150 columns in it. Now I want to create different views in the list based on the columns needed and for the each view i want a different SharePoint default add, edit and view form. Is this feasible ?
If not, than what else we can do to achieve this.

Any help on this will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use content type. Every view belongs to a single content type. Every content type has related fields in it and different add and edit forms.

Comment: The question sounds like `ContentTypes` should have been used in the first place.